# Language of Repeating table shortcut menu in Infopath Form

Tags: infopath

I have SP 2013 ENG with SP Slovak Language pack installed in our environment. The problem I have is that some of the Infopath controls are not translated into Slovak. For example the shortcut menu of repeating table is still in English.

[image]

The form is server form published to farm.
Any idea how to change english commands "Insert/Remove" into another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually change these. Open the form in design mode. Right click on the repeating section and select the Repeating Section properties from the menu. In the Data tab, click Modify, then click Customize Commands. You can then label these however you would like.